# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Single]'

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

Why I'm getting the above error in this LINQ query - and how I can resolve it?

```
System.Nullable<float> totalFreight =
    (from cust in db.Customers
       join ord in db.Orders on cust.ordID equals ord.OrdID
      select ord.Freight).Sum();
```

**Note**: `Freight` attribute/column in Orders entity/table is of type `float?`. I'm using `EF Core 1.1` with `VS2015`.

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302045(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386928(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN examples.

**UPDATE 2**: I isolated the issue as follows. Moreover, I verified, by hovering the mouse over `ord.Freight` that Freight indeed is of type float:

```
var totalFreight =
        from cust in db.Customers
           join ord in db.Orders on cust.ordID equals ord.OrdID
          select ord.Freight

var testSum = totalFreight.Sum();
```

But still get the exact same error, this time at line: `var testSum = totalFreight.Sum();`

Comment: You are not storing the value of `Freight` you are storing the value of `Sum(Freight)`

Comment: @Jonesopolis But how about [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302045(v=vs.110).aspx) example where `sum` is returning **float?**?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Could you please explain more with a suggestion. I've added an UPDATE section to my post above where I've referred to official MSDN examples.

Comment: What's the type of the `Freight` *column in the database table*?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using SQL Server 2012 where the data type of `Freight` is `real`. If you are testing it on your side you may want to make sure you are using EF Core 1.1 - and if it's not working on your end as well you may want to report it here so other readers may note it as well. It seems like a bug in EF Core 1.1 to me.

Comment: @nam Confirming - same behavior on my side (latest EF Core 1.1.1). Apparently (yet another) bug.

Comment: Change the last select to select (float?)ord.Freight).Sum();

Comment: Bug report on EF repo: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7136
It is fixed and will be available in next release (2.0.0-preview1)